# How to invoke a method in wowza media server module using an HTTPProvider?

Tags: java, wowza

I am trying to create an HTTPProvider to access the methods in a java module.But I cannot invoke it properly. 
This is the error that I am getting :-

```
    at com.sparksupport.wowza.ModuleCheckStreamAndAutoRecordValidity.recordStream(ModuleCheckStreamAndAutoRecordValidity.java:93)
    at com.sparksupport.wowza.HTTPProviderToManageRecording.onHTTPRequest(HTTPProviderToManageRecording.java:99)
    at com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPRequestAdapter.service(HTTPRequestAdapter.java:33)
    at com.wowza.wms.server.ServerHandler.a(ServerHandler.java:641)
    at com.wowza.wms.server.ServerHandler.a(ServerHandler.java:375)
    at com.wowza.wms.server.ServerHandler.messageReceived(ServerHandler.java:487)
    at com.wowza.wms.server.ServerHandlerThreaded.messageReceived(ServerHandlerThreaded.java:78)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$2.messageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:181)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:511)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$900(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:786)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.support.SimpleProtocolDecoderOutput.flush(SimpleProtocolDecoderOutput.java:60)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:511)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain.access$900(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:42)
    at org.apache.mina.common.support.AbstractIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(AbstractIoFilterChain.java:786)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter.processEvent(ExecutorFilter.java:247)
    at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter$ProcessEventsRunnable.run(ExecutorFilter.java:323)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ModuleCheckStreamAndAutoRecordValidity is the module and HTTPProviderToManageRecording is my HTTPProvider. What I did is that, I have created an object of the module in my httpprovider and using that I invoke the method recordStream(arguments).
```

Comment: please format your question